# Output A4 sized table in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, printing, barcode

Required to output (for print) generated barcodes of selected products in A4 paper format.

I finished all other parts of project, but can't figure out, how can I output, 5x13 table with barcodes. My barcodes are in PNG image format.

1. Is that possible with standard PHP libraries? (I'm using shared hosting, so I can't install additional php libraries.)
2. Which is possible or good for this purpose: to output PDF or HTML?
   Which is optimal?
3. Any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Why not use a print.css file, do a google search for print css, you can do some nifty things, the page you print can be totally different from the html page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of your table will depend on the resolution.

```
72 dpi (web) = 595 X 842 pixels
300 dpi (print) = 2480 X 3508 pixels
600 dpi (print) = 4960 X 7016 pixels
```

PDF would be optimal as there is so much variation in how different browsers render HTML/CSS. You can use a class called [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to generate those if you are down for a slight learning curve. There is also the built-in [PDFlib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php) in PHP you could try.